# dynamic scope vs lexical scope results

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

what will be returned using chez scheme - dynamic scope?

```
> (define x 0)
> ((lambda(x) x) 10)
> x
```

Our opinion is that the last value of x will be returned: 10 (when it passed as a parameter to the function). Is this correct?
Will the result be 0 on lexical scope?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll get an error since `10` is not a procedure.. Perhaps you mean to pass `(lambda () 10)` instead of `10` or perhaps it was not the intention to `apply` `x` by wrapping in parentheses? Dynamic/Lexcical scope only makes a difference for free variables and there are non in your example. Chez is a Scheme and it does not have dynamic scope. CL has both.

Comment: It is much easier and faster to test your hypothesis using Chez Scheme by evaluating the code than to ask strangers on the internet. (Even if Scheme had dynamic scope, the result would be 0.)